# Tutorials for Writing Common Code for use on Windows, OS X, iOS, and potentially Android

Tags: windows, ios, cross-platform

I'm looking at writing an application that I would like to use on Windows, OSX, and iOS (maybe pushing into Android if other people want to use it).  I want to duplicate as little work as possible and I'm having a hard time finding information on the best way to do this.

From what I've found so far I can't use a framework like QT because iOS doesn't support QT so it looks like I'm stuck recreating the interface for each target.  I'm looking at writing the business logic in C++ because it seems to be supported by the native tools (Visual Studio and xCode).

Has anyone had experience with a setup like this and if so can you point me towards a good reference for this kind of development?

Comment: You should read up on current Qt, the trolls never stand still: http://www.iphoneworld.ca/news/2010/12/08/nokias-qt-framework-works-great-for-iphone-ios-apps-development/ Same goes for Android, there are serious efforts to replicate wat happens for iOS for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Really there it not a lot of choice right now.  Qt is certainly coming to iOS and WP7 so C++ is a good solid evolving platform.

However there is also the mono project which offers C# across platforms.

http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid

From my understanding, you write in c# and it compiles to the platforms preferred language.